# Go to parent with with refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, state, angular-ui-router

When in a child state how can I transition back to its parent state with a refresh of that parent state?

My states are:

```
.state('user.things', {
    url: '/things',
    views: {
        "content@user": { 
            templateUrl: "partials/user/things/index.html",
            controller: 'thingIndexController' 
        }
    }
})
.state('user.things.show', {
    url: '/{id}',
    views: {
        "current-thing": { 
            templateUrl: "partials/user/things/show.html",
            controller: 'thingShowController' 
        }
    }
})
```

I have tried the following with no success of any code in `'user.things'` running after the state transition. The url does change and I do appear to be in that state, but no code in the controller runs.

```
$scope.deleteThing = function () {
    thingService.delete($stateParams.id).then(function () {
        $state.go('user.things', {}, { reload: true});
        // $state.to('user.things', {}, { reload: true});
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it properly. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwQQACGjNzDOpBmVF0Ym?p=preview) with your approach.

All is the same as in your use case:

```
.controller('thingShowController', ['$scope', '$state', 'thingService',
    function ($scope, $state, thingService) { 
      $scope.deleteThing = function () {
        thingService.remove($scope.$stateParams.id).then(function () {
            $state.go('user.things', {}, { reload: true});
            // $state.to('user.things', {}, { reload: true});
        });
    };
}])
```

> *NOTE: The only change (but not the essential) is that I replaced `delete` with **`remove`**. It is not needed, but delete is a keyword, and it is not so smart to use it...*

So, this example should help you to observe working solution and find differences in your own code.

Check the [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwQQACGjNzDOpBmVF0Ym?p=preview)

Some hint: maybe the real issue is inside of your service `thingService` and its `.delete()` function - returning promise. It could be, that this returns error...

And it could mean, that `.then()` as defined above won't be fired... Check the promise error handling **[Angular js - `$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)**

```
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your right I am getting a failure with a reason of:

Failed: Error: transition prevented

Although the url does change.